# Drop down filter sort posts by latest, last 7 days and monthly

Tags: filters, get-posts, sort

I am trying to use a drop down for users to select and show posts made latest, last 7 days and monthly.

Currently I was able to find code to just sort by date in ASC and DESC order.

```
<div id="sortby"> SORT BY: &nbsp;
    <select class="dropdown-class" name="sort-posts" id="sortbox" onchange="document.location.search=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option disabled>Sort by</option>
    <option <?php if( isset($_GET["orderby"]) && trim($_GET["orderby"]) == 'date' && isset($_GET["order"]) && trim($_GET["order"]) == 'DESC' ){ echo 'selected'; } ?> value="?orderby=date&order=DESC">Newest</option>
    <option <?php if( isset($_GET["orderby"]) && trim($_GET["orderby"]) == 'date' && isset($_GET["order"]) && trim($_GET["order"]) == 'ASC' ){ echo 'selected'; } ?>  value="?orderby=date&order=ASC">Oldest</option>
    </select>
    </div>
```

What I would like to do is add to that and show posts from the last 7 days and posts within the month. Any ideas how I would get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

The request to the server is in this phrase: `value="?orderby=date&order=DESC">`. That is a [`WP_query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) string. You would use a `date_query` with the `after` argument to construct a query that will return posts which were published after a certain date. Note that the string will be different every time, since it depends on the current date and time.

Once you have the query, you can pass it through [`add_query_arg`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/) to retrieve a string which you can include in your dropdown option.